# Live streaming byte image data through react from a server url

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm trying to get a React page to continuously render image data as a "live stream" from a local camera. The render function of the React page looks like:

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <img src="http://192.*.*.*:5002/camera/stream" width="640" height="480"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

On page load, only the first image gets rendered and that's it. No additional images get rendered.

The camera is sending image data in bytes through that url: `http://192.*.*.*:5002/camera/stream`
Beginning output of each looks like:

```
b'--FRAME\r\n\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00\x84\x00\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x03\
...
```

I've verified that the image data is sent continuously when visiting the url directly.

This might be a silly implementation of this, but am I missing something in the render function to tell react to continuously render the image from the url? Or is there a better way to implement similar functionality?